# Android device with USB HUB and Charge

Tags: usb, charging, usb-on-the-go

I have a Chinese android tablet with MTK8392. It has only 1 micro USB port. The OTG function is working well, I can use a special USB keyboard with OTG.

Is there ANY way to use this USB keyboard AND charge the tablet simultaneously? If it helps, I can use an active USB hub with self charge.
I bought a cable from dealextreme called "Micro 5 Pin USB OTG Data / Charging Connection Cable" but it's not working..

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing and after a bit of googling found a couple of plausible options:

1. [Acasis H027 Mobile Tablet PC Charging Cable OTG Micro USB HUB 3Ports Simultaneous Charging Power Transmisson Cable Black](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Acasis-H027-Charging-Simultaneous-Transmisson/dp/B00SZNT0ZU) - looks no name, and there are similar producs on [AliExpress](http://www.banggood.com/4-Port-Micro-USB-OTG-Charger-HUB-Cable-For-Tablet-Phone-p-975460.html?p=QZ14021624945201505Y). relevant links: [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCsBK14wH6U), [this forum post](http://techtablets.com/forum/topic/usb-otg-and-charge/)
2. [Dell Micro USB Dongle for Data and Charging](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=470-ABES) - more expensive and less ports, but hopefully more reliable brand

Additionally, if you're interested on the electronics side of it, [this electornics stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a) post looks very interesting. Slightly off topic, [this PoE Android project](http://hioproject.org/hio-development-kit/) looks interesting too.

**Update** The Dell Dongle arrived today and I tested it. It works but I found one minor caveat: the dongle needs to connected first, then power (microUSB), then the USB device. I didn't have success with a difference connection sequence. (I tested on a Nexus 7 tablet on Android 6.0.1 and a Lenovo smartphone running Android 4.2.1 using devices such as usb hub + usb stick + usb keyboard/mouse + usb to ethernet)

**Update2** The Acasis OTG Micro USB HUB arrived today. While the Dell Dongle doesn't power the Android device every single time (unplugging/replugging required), the Acasis one surprisingly does. The only catch is it's switch needs to be set to position 3 (otherwise it powers the tabled but doesn't use the attached USB devices). It's also nicer that it provides 3 USB ports instead of 1 and it's cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the information, before I ran out of time I bought a Nexus 7, charged from custom docking station so I could use the USB properly. At least some info for legacy :P