# How to use OTG (ethernet) and power on Nexus 5X using Type C connector?

Tags: usb, charging, usb-on-the-go

I would like to both power and connect a Nexus 5X via Ethernet (using an USB to Ethernet adaptor).

Here's what I tried to far:

- a Type C OTG to USB Female adaptor: Ethernet adaptor works on it's own
- a Type C to microUSB adaptor + [power OTG cable/hub](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104983/android-device-with-usb-hub-and-charge/149394#149394): Power works, but OTG doesn't work

Is there a Type C OTG Cable that supports power/charing too, or a Type C powered USB Hub ?

Otherwise, is there a pinout for the Type C connector describing how to hack an OTG + power cable (similar to the microUSB pinouts on [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a)) ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you'll want to get a usb c to usb a adapter that also has a power in port [like this](http://www.banggood.com/BASEUS-USB-C-Type-C-to-USB-3_0-HUB-Adapter-Charging-Date-Sync-For-New-Macbook-Chromebook-LETV-Phone-p-1030330.html?p=QZ14021624945201505Y). Then you should be able to just plug in your ethernet adapter to the female usb a. If it's drawing too much power I've never had issues plugging usb hubs into otg cables so I can't see adding a powered usb hub into the mix being an issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nano(+1), I'll give that a go. 
So far I've tried this [Anker USB-C Hub with Ethernet and Power](https://www.anker.com/products/A8302041) and connected it to a 5V 3A power supply but it either powers but doesn't do Ethernet (if power is connected before Ethernet) or Ethernet and no power (if I connect Ethernet before power). I'd like both at the same time. I hope the one you recommend will work.

Comment: Unfortunately the link (the one on `banggood.com`) is dead now.